# Is it good idea to set up mail server Google Compute Engine or Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos7, google-compute-engine

I really would like to hear your idea and experiences in setting up mail server on Google Computer Engine or Amazon EC2. Is it possible to do so? Is there any recommendation?

Answer (score 2):

**EC2**

While amazon had some issues with blacklists in the early days of EC2, it has since become a reliable platform to host your mails on.
As for recommendations, you would probably want [to choose an image](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/finding-an-ami.html#finding-an-ami-console) that has the basic necessities already installed.

To save yourself some complexity and extra work, choosing an image with [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) already installed can help speed you up.

**For Google Compute Engine**

Google, fearing abuse, has [blocked some of the email related ports](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/).
As such you will need some more knowledge on the subject of email hosting.
And will most likely be using a third party email relay.

However, just like Azure, google has partnered with [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/).
And most of the tiers contain [a certain amount of free emails relayed](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid).

Comment: Really thanks for your comment and kind suggestion. I really considering google cloud engine but it's bit long journey for mail server installation and configuration.